# How can I access comand line like cmd.exe on my dedicated linux server?

Tags: php, windows-command-prompt, ffmpeg

I have installed the ffmpeg by composer in my local server(windows7) and everything is working good now the site is live on internet (server CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 kvm) and I need to install it to the server.

I dont know how to do this. I installed it on my local server by command line with composer. But I don't have any idea how to do this on my server.

I have this in in my `composer.json` file:

```
{ 
"require": { 
"php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "dev-master" 
} 
}
```

and then to install it locally I wrote this in my command line composer install.

I have no idea, how to do these on server I have the same composer.json file on server too but how can i access cmd line on my linux dedicated Server.

My local server is windows7 wamp.

Now I am on CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 kvm.

Comment: What flavor of Linux?

Comment: Also some major rewording is probably important for this. You refer to a server as "local server" and "the server" and I have no idea if these are two different servers or what's going on. It's kinda a slight mess and you may get better answers if you polish it. Sorry if english is a secondary language, simply trying to help.

Comment: sorry sir, i have updated the question my server is CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 kvm please help me ... its very imp for me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more properly addressed to Bluehost support.  They should give you the SSH information you need, if a shell is part of your plan.

Comment: And regarding that, even if they have an issue with SSH I explained that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the server I'm assuming you have

1. Valid credentials
2. SSH up

To access the machine on the Internet (assuming you don't have local access to it) you can download [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) in windows and enter the IP and hit Open and then your credentials. Or log in with a private key if this is how your hosting is set up. It kind of depends on how your hosting provider spun up the server but they almost always spin it up with SSH. How you log in with SSH depends on how they do it (example: [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) requires a private key)

If this isn't with a hosting provider and it's just in your basement or something, boot up locally and hit CTRL+ALT+F2 to drop to a shell.

I'll try to be more specific if you specify your hosting provider.

Comment: my hosting provider is bluehost.com and i am having a dedicated server with CENTOS 6.7 x86_64

Comment: i have all the rights and privliudges but i dont know how to access them as i am new to these please help me by providing some thing in details..

Comment: Please try to SSH in with Putty as linked and see what happens. If you don't have an account, it should be under Server > Access Management > Primary User. For help getting Sudo access/root, bluehost has this: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2358